# How to color citation brackets using hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, color

I want to color the brackets of inline citation like: **some text[9]** where it is written in latex like this `some text\cite{9}`. Now hyperref only colors the number "9" without the brackets "[]". Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I don't know about the color of the brackets, but consider to cite like `text~\cite{id}`, this inserts a blank space between the text and the citation which will not be broken by a line break.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The colour applies to the active link.  Given that you can put several references into the cite command, `\cite{paper1,paper2,paper8}`, and these would have to link to different places, it doesn't make much sense to include the brackets in the link area.

Comment: @AndrewSwann that is right, but if we have like 5 cites, it will write for example [1-5] so we don't have link for each citation, only to the first one.

Comment: You only get `[1-5]` if you load certain citation styles, standard `plain` will print `[1,3,2,5,4]` and each reference will be linked.  If you add a minimal working example as Marco Daniel requests, you tell us which packages and citation styles you are using and we can better answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `cite` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand{\citeleft}{\textcolor{red}{[}}
\renewcommand{\citeright}{\textcolor{red}{]}}
\begin{document}
Hello \cite{world}!
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{world} created some time ago
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, if you do something like \cite[Example 1]{world}.